# How to use a button as a spinButton

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub spin01_Change()
lab01.Caption = spin01.Value
```

If I keep pressing a spinButton the label continues to change, in a very high speed.
Is it possible to create the same bahaviour with a common button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the SpinButton's Delay property to something like 1000.  That seems to effectively change it to a one-click-at-a-time control.

Comment: @ Doug, there is no such a property - Delay - for buttons in Excel.

Comment: I was talking about a SpinButton on a UserForm.  It's also true for a worksheet ActiveX SpinButton.  What kind of SpinButton were you talking about?

Comment: I want to raplace the spinButton with a simple, common button - which has no delay property. So keeping pressing on the CommonButton I want to change a label continiously - as with spinButton.

Comment: I'm sorry!  I completely misunderstood your question.  I'm not sure why.  I thought the spinbutton was going to fast for you.  I don't know how you can make a regular button behave like a spinbutton.